# How to package another java project as an osgi dependency in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have a java project which contains just java code. It is depended on by a java plugin. I want to take the non-plugin project, and convert it into an osgi bundle and put both into a feature. I did this, however it can never find the class. It just throughs NoClassDefError everytime, yet everything appears to be fine. I created a second project with really simple configuration just to be sure:

MANIFEST.MF:

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
 Bundle-Name: Test
 Bundle-SymbolicName: test
 Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
 Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
 Export-Package: com.etc,
```

The jar is built correctly and deployed along with the real plugin, but when that plugin calls something which depends on "test" it never loads the classes, it just fails with `org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "something.something.tools" was unable to instantiate class "com.something.something.SomeTool".`

The jar which is generated is perfectly fine, it has all of the class files in there under `com.something.something` and the MANIFEST.MF file is there as well.

Comment: Does SomeTool.java contain default constructor ?

Comment: Yes the code is valid. If I run all of this as a plugin via plugin.xml it all loads in that eclipse instance. The difference is that that eclipse instance has `com.something.something` on its classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to be much easier if you just convert the non-plugin project to a plugin project. Right-click on the project in Package Explorer and choose `Configure > Convert to Plug-In Projects...` Then compose a feature from the two plugins using the normal Eclipse structure. Otherwise you have a lot of configuration to do by hand, and the Eclipse documentation won't help much because they expect everyone to use the dialogs.

If you are also using this project in a non-plugin context, the conversion to plugin should not cause any problems--there will just be some extra stuff in the jar which is ignored in the non-plugin usage scenario.